# Package xlwings error import UDF

Tags: python, anaconda, xlwings

I installed the package xlwings with anaconda with the following command line

```
pip install xlwings
```

(I updated to get the last version), then

```
xlwings addin install
```

But when I want import functions

[image]

When I tried this I have the following error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your interpreter field needs to be the full path to the python interpreter. 
It's also worth to try "xlwings quickstart myproject". It'll set up the xlwings environment for myproject for you.